# Passing the partial derivative under integral

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-derivative, chain-rule

I have an integral

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \int_{0}^{t} f(x(\tau),\tau) d\tau, $$

where $f=f(x,t)$ is a function of a dependent variable $x=x(t)$ and the independent variable $t$ (time).

Can I let the derivative enter under the integral sign? Under what conditions can I do that, and why?

Update: The motivation behind wanting to insert the partial derivative inside the integral before integrating is that I know from other facts (say, physics) that $\partial f/\partial x$ is another function $g(x,t)$ that is much simpler to integrate directly than $f$. Indeed, the form of $f$ may be unknown but the partial derivative of it is known.  For example in canonical transformations and Hamiltonian mechanics, $f$ could be a Hamiltonian $H(x,y;t)$ whose partial derivative $\partial H/\partial x=d y/dt$, making the integral exact and the result simply $\Delta y=y(t)-y(0)$. But I want to know if such tactic is rigorous.

Comment: Strictly speaking $f(x(\tau),\tau)$ does not depend on $x$, only on $\tau$, so the derivative is $0$. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: @Mick Hi. Please see post update for what I mean. Hope this clarifies it.

Comment: could you give a specific example from physics? because as mick said, in the way you have written things currently, the answer will be 0. Do you really want $x$ itself to depend on $\tau$? that being said, the Wikipedia page on Leibniz Integral rule is a good place to start

Comment: @peek-a-boo This question is of interest when you don't know the form of $f$ explicity to perform the integral, but you know its derivative's form. A specific example is in canonical tranformations and Hamiltonian mechanics: $f$ would be a Hamiltonian $H(x,t)$ whose partial derivative $\partial H/\partial x=d g/dt$, making the integral exact and the result $\Delta g=g(t)-g(0)$. But I want to know if such tactic is rigorous. The Wiki page you cited doesn't directly discuss this case, and I wanted a direct discussion, if I could find one.

Comment: once again, the way you have written things, the derivative of that integral will automatically be 0 because once you integrate, the result doesn't depend on x anymore. I'm sorry, but I think there's a huge discrepancy between what you wish to ask vs how you're phrasing it, and I'm not able to see how best to assist you

Comment: if you set $$g(u):=\int_\alpha ^\beta f(t,u(t))\mathop{}\!d t$$ for some $f\in C^{0,p}(T\times X,F)$ where $T$ is compact $X\subset E$ open and $E$ and $F$ Banach spaces then $$\partial g(u)h=\int_{\alpha }^{\beta }\partial _2 f(t,u(t))h(t)\mathop{}\!d t$$ for $u\in C([\alpha ,\beta ],X)$ and $h\in C([\alpha ,\beta ],E)$. For more information take a look at *Analysis II* of Herbert Amann and Joachim Escher, the chapter about Nemytskii operators. There is a general derivative when $\alpha $ and $\beta $ are functions